# RailsAdmin multiple lines in list view cell

Tags: actionview, rails-admin

I'd like to get RailsAdmin to show two fields in one cell.

```
config.model Model do
  list do
    field :id do
      label '#'
    end

    field :email do
      label 'Customer'
      formatted_value do
        view = bindings[:view]
        bindings[:view].content_tag(:div, [view.content_tag(:p, bindings[:object].email), view.content_tag(:p, bindings[:object].phone)])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This gives me the following output (escaped HTML basically).

```
[<p>...(email)...</p> <p>...(phone)...</p>]
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong - being a rails beginner, maybe I'm not using the content_tag method correctly?

Comment: I'm unable to answer my own question for the next 8 hours, so here's the solution to this. Use a block and concatenate the other tags inside it:

    bindings[:view].content_tag(:div) do
      view.content_tag(:p, bindings[:object].phone).concat(view.content_tag(:p, bindings[:object].email))
    end